# read HDF5 file to pandas DataFrame with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a huge HDF5 file, I want to load part of it in a pandas DataFrame to perform some operations, but I am interested in filtering some rows.

I can explain better with an example:

Original HDF5 file would look something like:

```
A    B    C    D
1    0    34   11
2    0    32   15
3    1    35   22
4    1    34   15
5    1    31   9
1    0    34   15
2    1    29   11
3    0    34   15
4    1    12   14
5    0    34   15
1    0    32   13
2    1    34   15
etc  etc  etc  etc
```

What I am trying to do is to load this, exactly as it is, to a pandas Dataframe but only `where A==1 or 3 or 4`

Until now I can just load the whole HDF5 using:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('Resutls2015_10_21.h5')
df = pd.DataFrame(store['results_table'])
```

I do not see how to include a `where` condition here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `hdf5` file must be written in [`table` format](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#fixed-format) (as opposed to `fixed` format) in
order to be queryable with `pd.read_hdf`'s `where` argument.

Furthermore, `A` must be [declared as a data_column](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#query-via-data-columns):

```
df.to_hdf('/tmp/out.h5', 'results_table', mode='w', data_columns=['A'],
          format='table')
```

or, to specify all columns as (queryable) data columns:

```
df.to_hdf('/tmp/out.h5', 'results_table', mode='w', data_columns=True,
          format='table')
```

Then you could use

```
pd.read_hdf('/tmp/out.h5', 'results_table', where='A in [1,3,4]')
```

to select rows where the value column `A` is 1, 3 or 4. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
    'B': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'C': [34, 32, 35, 34, 31, 34, 29, 34, 12, 34, 32, 34],
    'D': [11, 15, 22, 15, 9, 15, 11, 15, 14, 15, 13, 15]})

df.to_hdf('/tmp/out.h5', 'results_table', mode='w', data_columns=['A'],
          format='table')

print(pd.read_hdf('/tmp/out.h5', 'results_table', where='A in [1,3,4]'))
```

yields

```
    A  B   C   D
0   1  0  34  11
2   3  1  35  22
3   4  1  34  15
5   1  0  34  15
7   3  0  34  15
8   4  1  12  14
10  1  0  32  13
```

---

If you have a very long list of values, `vals`, then you could use string formatting to compose the right `where` argument:

```
where='A in {}'.format(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu, just some comments on this good answer. I understand that, at the begining of your answer you write the df to h5 in table format. However, the input to my script is a h5 already saved, how can I know if it is in the correct format or not?

Comment: If your `h5` file is not in `table` format, then using `pd.read_hdf` with the `where` parameter will raise `TypeError: cannot pass a where specification when reading from a Fixed format...`. If the `h5` file is in `table` format by `A` was not specified as a `data_column`, then you would get `ValueError: The passed where expression: A in [1,3,4] contains an invalid variable reference...`.

Comment: I don't know of a quick/easy way to convert an h5 file from `fixed` to `table` format, or to add `data_columns`. As far as I know, you would have to read the entire `h5` file into a DataFrame (or to do so in chunks using the `chunksize` parameter) and then to write it out or append to a different `h5` file in `table` format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `pandas.read_hdf` ([here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html)), with the optional parameter of `where`.
For [example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#id3): `read_hdf('store_tl.h5', 'table', where = ['index>2'])`

Comment: Thanks Dean, is it possible to include more complex conditions? like for example, if my A column has values from 1 to 100 and I want to select something random like [1,3,11,16,27,33,34,44,41,55,68,70,77,81,90]...I am asking that because in the main question I wanted to make it easy, but in my real case the `where` condition would need to be more complex

Comment: Found the documentation for the Expr you need to pass to where: http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.computation.pytables.Expr?fulldoc=1 (This might be helpful, though I don't see an option for filtering by containment)