# hdf5 file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I downloaded a dataset which is stored in .h5 files.
I need to keep only certain columns and to be able to manipulate the data in it.

To do this, I tried to load it in a pandas dataframe. I've tried to use:

```
pd.read_hdf(path)
```

But I get: `No dataset in HDF5 file.`

I've found answers on SO ([read HDF5 file to pandas DataFrame with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451926/read-hdf5-file-to-pandas-dataframe-with-conditions)) but I don't need conditions, and the answer adds conditions about how the file was written but I'm not the creator of the file so I can't do anything about that.

I've also tried using h5py:

```
df = h5py.File(path)
```

But this is not easily manipulable and I can't seem to get the columns out of it (only the names of the columns using `df.keys()`)
Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: I think my answe here and the provided links might be of help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74127100/5838180

Answer (score 15):

Easiest way to read them into Pandas is to convert into `h5py`, then `np.array`, and then into `DataFrame`. It would look something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(h5py.File(path)['variable_1']))
```

Comment: What does 'variable_1' represent in this case? - I am having the same issue opening .h5 files

Comment: variable_1 would be a single dataset. A file in h5py is supposed to be a dictionary of labeled datasets. So "h5py.File(path)" returns a dictionary and then accessing ["variable_1"] on that returns the value for the key "variable_1" which is a single dataset.

Answer (score 7):

Pandas HDF support needs the HDF file to be formated very specifically. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644128/4128030 for more info.

Comment: Yes. More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787168/4653485) as well.