# What is the fastest way to read HDF5 attribute and convert to Pandas data frame when working with large files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, h5py

I am working with 4-50 GB HDF5 files. One file has an HDF5 Group (`"outer_group"`) with several subgroups. The last subgroup (`"sub_sub_group"`) has a dataset (`"dataset1"`), which I want to read and convert to a Pandas data frame. `"dataset1"` contains four columns `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`, and `"D"` and mixed data types (string, numeric, byte, etc).

- test_file.h5

  - outer_group

    - sub_group

      - sub_sub_group

        - dataset1

This is how I am currently loading the data into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd

f = h5py.File("test_file.h5", "r")

values_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    f["outer_group"]["sub_group"]["sub_sub_group"]["dataset1"][()], 
    columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    )
```

However, this takes several minutes to load. Does anyone know of a faster solution for loading the `"dataset1"` hdf5 attribute to a Pandas data frames when working with large files? I have looked into `read_hdf` and `HDF_Store`, but I am not sure how to access the specific attribute. I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987891/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-pandas-dataframe-that-is-stored-as-a-group-in-a-hdf5) that my current approach (combining h5py with Pandas) might lead to issues.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried pd.read_hdf("./test_file.h5", key='/outer_group/sub_group/sub_sub_group/dataset1')

Comment: `f["outer_group"]["sub_group"]["sub_sub_group"]["dataset1"][()]` should be producing a structured `numpy` array.  What's array/dataframe size?  I haven't seen speed comparisons, but as far as I know, `h5py` does a fairly direct load of the `HDF5` source, so should be competitive.

Comment: @Rushikesh, thank you; that answers how to access the specific attribute. It turned out that pd.read_hdf() took 100 seconds, compared to 83 seconds with h5py and pd.DataFrame.from_records.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your input. The array shape is (10852708, 4). The h5py.File method + pd.DataFrame.from_records completed after 83 seconds. I wonder if this is the standard expectation for timing for an array this large.

Comment: If you read it into a numpy array (`f...['dataset1'][()]`) and then convert that to pandas afterwards, how long does each step take? That might show which bit is slow. And how big is one dataset in bytes?